# Mysterious highlight generated by material + mesh combo?

Tags: mesh, materials

**SOLUTION:** It was simply a matter of selecting the mesh and Object Context Menu > Shade Flat; it was previously set to Shade Smooth.

---

Here's the file: [Blend file](https://www.arcadiastreet.com/share/strange_texture_artifact.blend)

I've got a nice material for solar panels, but the problem is that when combined with a the solar panel mesh a triangular highlight appears that I cannot make go away.

At first I thought it was a glint of sunlight, but the unwanted highlight remains regardless of the sun angle.

If I apply the solar panel material to a simple plane, there is no unwanted highlight, and if I apply a generic glossy material to the solar panel mesh, there is also no unwanted highlight. It seems the problem stems from the combination of the solar panel material and the solar panel mesh.

I can't figure it out. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.0/KCyclesX 3.01, Windows 11

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: @Chris thank you for the response. I attached a blend file to my OP.

Comment: Fresnel is a value that goes from 0 to 1 based on viewing angle. You are choosing between two materials based on the angle between the viewer and the viewed plane.

Comment: @RonJensen thank you. The Fresnel node is pretty cool. What I'm trying to figure out is why it's creating that highlight artifact on one corner of the mesh. I'm assuming it has something to do with the mesh itself? (The highlight is independent of the orientation of the mesh to the camera and light source.)